# How to understand the definition of empirical distribution function

Tags: distributions, nonparametric

I am reading the [*All of Nonparametric Statistics*](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee378a/books/book2.pdf), by Larry Wasserman.
At page 12, he defines the empirical distribution function as:

The **empirical distribution function** $\hat{F_n}$ is the CDF that puts mass $\frac{1}{n}$ at each data point $X_i$. Formally,

$$\hat{F_n}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1}I(X_i\le x)$$

where

$$I(X_i\le x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 1& if\ X_i \le x\\ 
0 & if \ X_i>x
\end{matrix}\right.$$

My questions are:

1. Why is $\frac{1}{n}$ called mass?
2. The CDF puts mass $\frac{1}{n}$ to each data point $X_i$, then, by my understanding, it should be $\frac{1}{n}X_1+\frac{1}{n}X_2+...+\frac{1}{n}X_n$.

Why is it $\hat{F_n}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{i=1}I(X_i\le x)$? I think this formula puts mass $\frac{1}{n}$ on each indicator function $I(X_i \le x)$ but not $X_i$.

What is the meaning of "puts" something "at each data point"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why is $\frac{1}{n}$ called mass?

The term "mass" refers to an amount of probability at a single discrete point, as distinct from "density" in relation to continuous distributions.

> The CDF puts mass $\frac{1}{n}$ to each data point $X_i$, then, by my understanding, it should be $\frac{1}{n}X_1+\frac{1}{n}X_2+...+\frac{1}{n}X_n$.

That isn't a question, it's a statement -- but your understanding given there is mistaken in a couple of ways at once, so I can discuss that.

First the expression $\frac{1}{n}X_1+\frac{1}{n}X_2+...+\frac{1}{n}X_n$ is actually an expression for the *sample mean* (as a random variable) -- it literally means to average the values. I presume that you meant instead to write an expression for the empirical probability function here -- but keep in mind that we're meant to be dealing with a *distribution function*, not the probability function, so you need to find the proportion of the empirical probability that's at or *to the left of* each possible value of $x$ -- that's how a distribution function represents probability 1/n at each point:

[image: empirical probability function and empirical cdf]

These are two different representations of the same underlying object. You can see that the empirical pmf shows a mass of 1/n at each observed value, while the ecdf shows a height that increases by 1/n at each observed value (and that this corresponds to 1/n times the sum of indicator functions you mentioned)

> What is the meaning of "puts" something "at each data point"?

I'm not quite sure exactly what causes the difficulty here, the words essentially take their ordinary meanings; see the images above which show a proportion of $1/n$ at each observed value $x_i$; if you treat the epmf and the ecdf as a pmf and a cdf respectively, those are probabilities. Possibly it is treating  $\hat{F}$ as an active entity (one that can "put" things somewhere) that is confusing you -- would it be easier to understand if it said "has" rather than "puts"? If that doesn't help, you'll have to make it clearer what you need explained there.