# Empirical distribution for feature binning

Tags: feature-engineering, histogram, binning, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

In paper "A simple yet effective baseline for non-attributed graph classification" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.03508.pdf) authors use empirical distribution for feature binning. Precisely, they have 5 features, and for each feature:

> We aggregate features over different nodes in the same graph by performing either a histogram or an empirical distribution function(edf) operation, i.e, mapping all node feature into a histogram or an empirical distribution.

> Empirical Distribution versus Histogram. We try to represent node features over a graph by both a histogram or an empirical distribution because empirical distribution is more stable with respect with the particular choice of bin size.

Histogram is obvious - I take the smallest and largest value, divide the range e.g. into 10 bins, and count value occurrences (for equal-width binning). However, I do not understand how to use EDF here.

**Question:** what does it mean in this context to use empirical distribution function? How do I calculate values e.g. for a single feature, given set of its values? Is it just a cumulative distribution function, calculated using those values?

Comment: Here is an explanation of what the [empirical distribution function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265910/how-to-understand-the-definition-of-empirical-distribution-function) is, with formulas and figures.